# Atom Syntax Grammar Names

Tags: less, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am working on a Language Package in Atom and am curious about how to name items.  For some reason, things like `keyword.operator.langname` as the name, yet it still doesn't highlight.  I checked the HTML source and the span is there, but no coloring.  I even compared my code to other languages code and the styles.less file used in atom and it appears that it should work.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there any good place that has a list of the selectors as I can't seem to find any docs on them.

The regex I am using for anyone who is curious is:

`'match': ':', 
'name': 'keyword.operator.langname'`

(langname being a psuedonym for the name of the language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the syntax theme you're using doesn't support it. I know that `keyword.operator` shows up in `language-javascript`, but when I look at `one-dark-syntax` as an example, the coloring for that class combination only exists in [language-specific files](https://github.com/atom/one-dark-syntax/blob/master/styles/syntax/javascript.less). I feel like the best path for people designing small language packages is to look in core syntax theme packages to figure out which classes to use. Don't get too hung up on the actual class *names*, since your user won't see them at all unless they look at them in the dev tools.